# Angular 2 - Routing in service

Tags: angular

I created a service to check for user token.

If the token hasn't expired, do nothing. if it's expired - redirect him to the login page.

**My Service.ts relevant code:**

```
checkToken(myError) {
        if (myError.json().error == "token_expired")
        {
            console.log("Your token has expired.");
            this.router.navigate( ['Login'] ); //Returns error
        } else {
            console.log("Do nothing");
        }
    }
```

**The problem**

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

My Service.ts

```
    import {Component,Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';


@Injectable()

export class JwtService {
    private jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    constructor(public router: Router) 

    getToken() {
        return this.jwtToken;
    }

    checkToken(myError) {
        if (myError.json().error == "token_expired")
        {
            console.log("Your token has expired.");
            this.router.navigate( ['Login'] );
        } else {
            console.log("Do nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

My `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is in my `boot.ts` file:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  JwtService,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

then why I can't navigate from my service?

Comment: Looks like you have `@Injectable()` on the component which is redundant.

Comment: You inject the `Router` to `AppComponent` but use it in your service. Do you inject the `Router` to the service as well?

Comment: I already use it in my `AppComponent`, but now I need to use it in my service too. The code in my post is from my service.

Comment: Please add the class name and constructor to your service code. You still have `@Injectable()` above `@Component({ ...` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: But why does you `JwtService` class have a `@Component()` decorator?

Comment: How do I suppose to add my `[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` then?

Comment: `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` are only required on components for `<router-outlet>` or `<a [routerLink]>`. `Router`, `RouteParams`, ... are provided by `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`. `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in `bootstrap()` is enough (don't add it anywhere else). `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` need to be added to each component where the directives are used.

Comment: Yep that's it! What a silly error, adding brackets have fixed the problem. Seem like the router got null because there were no brackets. Thank you sir!

Comment: I run into this as well. Seems the constructor is ignored if it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(public router: Router)
```

should be

```
constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! but I changed my code to this:`@Injectable()

@Component({
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})` and still same error appears

Comment: I didn't expect this to solve your issue but a comment seemed to hard to decipher with some lines of code. I need more information about your code  (see comment on your question).